# Filtering mongodb data collection filter

Tags: c#, mongodb, filtering, driver

I used mongodb in my backend to store some customer personal information and I need to fetch the user who ages 30, 32 and 35.

I tried below ways to get but it returns zero results and I used C# MongoDB.Driver

### C# code

```
Age = new string[] { "26-30", "31-35" }
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
var filter = Builders<Customer>.Filter.Empty;
foreach (var item in searchFilterBlock.Age)
 {
    var ageBetween = item.Split('-');
    int.TryParse(ageBetween[0], out int startYear);
    int.TryParse(ageBetween[1], out int endYear);
    var start = today.AddYears(-startYear);
    var end = today.AddYears(-endYear); 
    filter = filter & (Builders<Customer>.Filter.Gte(x => x.Dob, start)
                        & Builders<Customer>.Filter.Lte(x=>x.Dob, end));
 }
```

```cs
// to execute the filter
var searchResult = _context.Customer.Find(filter).ToList(); // it return 0 result
```

Need to get who has ages 30, 32 and 35.

Comment: your code suggests you are trying to find customers who are aged 26 to 30 and 31 to 35. your question says you need customers who are exactly 30, 32 and 35 years old. which one do you need exactly?

Answer (score 0):

you can get customers who are aged 30,32 and 35 by using an `$or` filter like the following:

```java
db.Customer.find({
    "$or": [
        {
            "DOB": {
                "$lte": ISODate("1989-06-22T14:57:50.168Z"),
                "$gte": ISODate("1988-06-22T14:57:50.168Z")
            }
        },
        {
            "DOB": {
                "$lte": ISODate("1987-06-22T14:57:50.168Z"),
                "$gte": ISODate("1986-06-22T14:57:50.168Z")
            }
        },
        {
            "DOB": {
                "$lte": ISODate("1984-06-22T14:57:50.168Z"),
                "$gte": ISODate("1983-06-22T14:57:50.168Z")
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

here's the c# code that generated the above find query using the convenience library [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities) [disclaimer: i'm the author]

```cs
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Customer : Entity
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            (new[] {
                new Customer{ Name = "I am 29", DOB = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-29)},
                new Customer{ Name = "I am 30", DOB = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-30)},
                new Customer{ Name = "I am 32", DOB = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-32)},
                new Customer{ Name = "I am 35", DOB = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-35)},
                new Customer{ Name = "I am 36", DOB = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-36)}
            }).Save();

            var ages = new[] { 30, 32, 35 };

            var filters = new List<FilterDefinition<Customer>>();

            foreach (var age in ages)
            {
                var start = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-age);
                var end = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-age - 1);
                filters.Add(DB.Filter<Customer>()
                              .Where(c => c.DOB <= start && c.DOB >= end));
            }

            var customers = DB.Find<Customer>()
                              .Many(f => f.Or(filters))
                              .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```